# height of emacs bottom command line

Tags: emacs, elisp

How do I change the height of the emacs bottom command line. It seems it's a fraction of the whole frame, which takes too much space. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The minibuffer can automatically take the minimal amount of space required.  There is some tweaking that you can do to help it use space more effectively. From the [Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-Edit.html):

> Normally, the minibuffer window
>   occupies a single screen line.
>   However, if you add two or more lines'
>   worth of text into the minibuffer, it
>   expands automatically to accomodate
>   the text. The variable
>   `resize-mini-windows` controls the
>   resizing of the minibuffer. The
>   default value is `grow-only`, which
>   means the behavior we have just
>   described. If the value is `t`, the
>   minibuffer window will also shrink
>   automatically if you remove some lines
>   of text from the minibuffer, down to a
>   minimum of one screen line. If the
>   value is `nil`, the minibuffer window
>   never changes size automatically, but
>   you can use the usual window-resizing
>   commands on it (see [Windows](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows.html)).

Comment: For the win. But you might highlight the variable name.

Answer (score 2):

According to GNU Emacs manual, [section 8.3 Editing in the Minibuffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer-Edit.html#index-max_002dmini_002dwindow_002dheight-188):

> The variable `max-mini-window-height` controls the maximum height for resizing the minibuffer window. A floating-point number specifies a fraction of the frame's height; an integer specifies the maximum number of lines; `nil` means do not resize the minibuffer window automatically. The default value is 0.25.

In Emacs Lisp manual it is described in [section 20.14 Minibuffer Miscellany](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Minibuffer-Misc.html#index-max_002dmini_002dwindow_002dheight-1283).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the [minibuffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minibuffer.html)?

Using `C-h v minibuffer <tab>` will give you a list of minibuffer related variable and if you finish the command give you the help.

Likewise, `C-h f minibuffer <tab>` will give you a list of minibuffer related function.

I don't see anything obvious that would effect the height of the buffer.